# How much weight do I lose when I run a mile?

Tags: running, weight-loss, calculation

How much weight do I lose when I run a mile in 15 to 17 minutes?

I am 82 yearls old, 154lbs, 5 ft 7.5 inches tall and medium build.

Comment: Do you mean immediately after running or over a period of time? Are you talking about fat mass or just water weight? Are you in a caloric deficit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to know how much weight you lose when you run is to weigh yourself before and after the run, and subtract the weight of any food or drink you consumed.

Explanation - It's not really feasible to figure out how much "weight" you lost. Generally speaking, a person will burn about 100 calories per mile traveled. And yes, it's fairly consistent at any pace. If you cover 5 miles, you'll burn around 500 calories. Runners will do it in less time, walkers in more, but the calories are the same. While 3500 calories = 1 lb of weight loss is a myth, as long as you consistently burn more than you consume, you will lose weight.

The other reason you can't really calculate weight loss per exercise session is that the muscles burn glycogen which also reduces weight, you sweat which reduces weight, it's just not a calculable number.

Best is to weigh before and after, drink to replace fluid loss, and measure weight over time to see if it is going up or down.